# Validar la extensión del archivo con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tengo un código hecho en para aceptar cierto tipo de extensión de archivos, como se muestra a continuación, pero lo que debo realizar es que solo aparezcan en la ventana emergente el tipo de archivos permitidos y no todos como me aparezca a mí. Ejemplo: si deseo abrir un `xlsx` solo debe de aparece ese y no imágenes o vídeos

```js
$(document).on('change', 'input[type="file"]', function() {
  var fileName = this.files[0].name;
  var fileSize = this.files[0].size;
  var ext = fileName.split('.').pop();

  switch (ext) {
    case 'xlsx':
      $('#tamanoArchivo').text(fileSize + " bytes");
      break;
    case 'csv':
      $('#tamanoArchivo').text(fileSize + " bytes");
      break;
    default:
      alert('El archivo no tiene la extensión adecuada');
      this.value = ''; // reset del valor
      this.files[0].name = '';
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
 <input id="campoFile" accept=”application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet” name="archivo" type="file" value="" />
 <p id="tamanoArchivo"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No creo que sea posible desde la ventana emergente, input['file'] es muy restrictivo https://stackoverflow.com/a/37832463/1160992.

Comment: Fijate si esto funciona: `<input type="file" accept=".gif,.jpg,.jpeg,.png,.doc,.docx">`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796537/input-type-file-limit-selectable-files-by-extensions

Comment: El problema es que tienes mal las comillas del atributo accept. Si te fijas tienes ” en vez de " (seguramente por un copy/paste). Cámbialas por " y te funcionará.

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
$(document).on('change','input[type="file"]',function(){   
   
   var fileName = this.files[0].name;
   var fileSize = this.files[0].size;

    var ext = fileName.split('.');
                // ahora obtenemos el ultimo valor despues el punto
                // obtenemos el length por si el archivo lleva nombre con mas de 2 puntos
                ext = ext[ext.length-1];

    switch (ext) {
     case 'xlsx':
      $('#tamanoArchivo').text(fileSize+" bytes en "+ext);
     break; 
     case 'csv': 
      $('#tamanoArchivo').text(fileSize+" bytes "+ext);
     break;
     default:
      alert('El archivo no tiene la extensión adecuada');
      this.value = ''; // reset del valor
      this.files[0].name = '';
     break; 
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>


</head>
<body>
<input id="campoFile" accept=”application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet” name="archivo" type="file" value="" />
 <p id="tamanoArchivo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```